# Laravel : post delete in the destroy method is ambiguous when deleting

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am confused about wanting to delete a data according to id
the problem is that when you delete it, it's not the one from the cursor you're aiming at, it deletes it from the first id instead

web.php

```
 Route::resource('dashboard/posts', DashboardPostController::class)->names([
        'index' => 'post-dashboard',
        'show' => 'post-show',
        'create' => 'post-create',
        'edit' => 'post-edit',
        'destroy' => 'post-delete',
        'update' => 'post-edit'
    ]);
```

postcontroller.php

```
public function destroy(Post $post)
    {
        if ($post->image) {
            Storage::delete($post->image);
        }

        Post::destroy($post->id);

        $notif = [
            'message' => 'Data has been Deleted',
            'alert-type' => 'success'
        ];
        return redirect()->route('post-dashboard')->with($notif);
    }
```

post.blade.php /view

```
<form action="{{ route('post-delete', $post->slug) }}" method="POST" class="d-inline" id="deleteForm">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button type="button" class="badge bg-danger border-0">
        <i class="material-icons opacity-10" onclick=" confirmDelete()">cancel</i>
    </button>
</form>
```

post Models

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
  {
    return 'slug';
  }

public function sluggable(): array
  {
    return [
        'slug' => [
            'source' => 'title'
        ]
    ];
  }
```

anyone can help me please check my code

Comment: Check the `id` value in the sent HTTP request. Then on your your controller, log the value of `$post->id`. Are they not the same?

Comment: You already have the Post when you enter the `destroy()`.  You can change `Post::destroy($post->id);` into `$post->delete();`

Comment: i did sir but nothing my controller was changed not changed

Answer (score 0):

Need to Change in Destroy method inside the controller.

Use Model Eloquent delete facade for deleting the current record.

Change the destroy function with this code:

```
public function destroy(Post $post)
    {
        if ($post->image) {
            Storage::delete($post->image);
        }

        $post->delete();

        $notif = [
            'message' => 'Data has been Deleted',
            'alert-type' => 'success'
        ];
        return redirect()->route('post-dashboard')->with($notif);
    }
```

Comment: How exactly would `Post::delete();` delete a post **with a specific id**?

Comment: @brombeer
Update the code. Thanks for confirming